# Text "shaking" in CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a menu on my responsible site. The problem is: When I'm using Google Chrome (almost all the time) there's an error with the div's when I point the cursor (hover).

```
.barramenu {
    background-color:#000000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0%;
    box-shadow: 0vmin 0vmin 2vmin rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    list-style-type:none;
    z-index:1;
}

.barrafrente {
    position:absolute;
    width:51vmin;
    height:100%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    z-index:1;
}

.menu {
    width:51vmin;
    height:48vmin;
    position:absolute;
    left:0vmin;
    bottom:0vmin;
    text-align: right;
    z-index:2; 
    font: 3.9vmin 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height:5.8vmin;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

}

.menu1, .menu2, .menu3, .menu4, .menu5, .menu6 {
    width:100%;
    height:5.8vmin;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0vmin;
    margin-top:2.6vmin;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77ejbyxm/

The text seems like is "shaking"!

Comment: it doesn't shake for me in chrome.

Comment: same for me, it's not shaking

Comment: not shaking for me neither

Comment: Well, thank you Guys! I just don't know what is this..

Comment: You can try checking your padding or margins on hover state. I have had an issue similar to that and it was because my padding or margin was changing on hover which was in turn shaking my links up and down.

Comment: @ZecaNovaes, what version of chrome and what OS do you use?
Tested on Chrome 36.0.1985.143 and Mozilla 31.0 , Ubuntu 14.04 no shaking/flickering/tearing noticed.

Comment: It also may be worth noting that css transitions are hardware accelerated. Maybe its the device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements