# Chrome: Automatic shift of web elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

I'm working on a web project. In the last two weeks I was having my semester examinations so I'd to take  a break from it. Now, since they are over, I've resumed my work; but I find that some of my **web elements (like button,span) have shifted by some pixels on Chrome (not on IE and Mozilla)**. What could be the reason behind this? How do I overcome this problem?

**ORIGINAL CODE**: http://jsfiddle.net/p22L15vs/15/embedded/result/

The left margin (for ***button***) for chrome was originally:

```
-webkit-margin-start:620px;
```

Now the same code causes the button to enter a new line.

Another example of ***span***:

**ORIGINAL CODE**: http://jsfiddle.net/vbpasx1j/

The text shown in the fiddle was placed in a span tag. Two weeks ago it required only two lines. Now it requires three lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to due the headline change in Chrome 37 ,the introduction of DirectWrite support for Windows.
Check this link for further details:

http://www.omgchrome.com/google-chrome-37-arrives-improved-font-rendering-windows/

This feature has caused a similar issue for various developers.

In order to restore to your previous font, the solution is to disable this new feature in your browser. You need to follow the following steps:

---

1> Enter chrome://flags/ in your address bar.

2> In the Disable DirectWrite Windows section click on Enable (actually disables it).

3> Click on Relaunch Now at the bottom.

4> Restart your browser.

---

Your original page design remains unchanged. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to the community!
  First off, in your provided link the `-webkit-margin-start:` of the button is set to 620px, not 166.
  That, combined with the width of your menu div `<div id="div_element">` as well as the padding around your elements exceeds your original `#wrapper` width of 1006px, making the button element jump to the next row.
Here's a demo to a top-of-my-mind solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kqxmbcdt/
Reduce the `-webkit-margin-start:` to 619px and you're good to go. 
Always be on the lookout for unaccounted margins and paddings when positioning elements, as you can see, sometimes 1px is all it takes to break a layout.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was trying to adjust the margin so that it exactly fits the fiddle; but then decided for embedded result but forgot to make the changes (have edited now).

The issue is: it was working perfectly fine with a value of 620px, I know that changing it to 619px makes it inline. There are other elements which have also shifted by some amount.

Also my chrome automatically got updated to a new version (37.0.2062.103) which might be the reason for shift of elements. How do I make amendments for all of the shifted elements?

Comment: Could you provide some specification as to what these "other elements" and "some amount" are? If the link in your question is only a snippet, perhaps sharing the full code, or at least elaborating a bit more,  would help us crack the problem.

Comment: Here's a link that might shed some light on the latest Chrome update. http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2363651/chrome-37-arrives-on-desktop-android-and-chrome-os
From what I gather, the new DirectWire is what might have caused the shift in your layout. Try fiddling with the font-size of your <div id="div_element">. Reducing it down to even 11.9px brings the button back up on the same row, without having to change widths. A more sensible solution would be to do a rehaul on your site and reorder the layout.

Comment: I've added a fiddle for span in the problem description. You can check this link as well: http://jsfiddle.net/vbpasx1j/

Comment: Other developers are also facing the similar issue. Check the comments section in the following link:
http://www.omgchrome.com/google-chrome-37-arrives-improved-font-rendering-windows/