# Original working CSS Hover Animation Not Working-CHROME ONLY

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Note that this was working for me a couple of weeks ago but it stopped working. I don't know if Chrome's recent update broke this code or not.

I had a hover animation in which when you hover over "Free Trial" the rest of the div slides smoothly into view and when the user stops hovering, there is another slide effect that hides majority of the div. Ultimately I am trying to show a button when the hover is in effect, but hide it when the mouse is taken off of the `#trial` div.

The issue is not that it doesn't work at all. The issue is when the user hovers it THE FIRST TIME the effect doesn't ease-in/transition-duration doesn't work. The first hover gets skipped then all hovers after that work.

This was working a couple of weeks ago. Could Chrome's new update have caused this issue to happen? I tested this in internet explorer and it doesn't seem to work. Please use Chrome to test out the fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE FOR CHROME ONLY](http://jsfiddle.net/q75x97zj/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="trial" style="position:fixed; right:0; top:80px; z-index:999; display:inline;vertical-align:middle;">
            <h1 style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width:80px;padding-right:30px;">Free Trial!</h1>
            <p style="display:inline-block; width:300px;vertical-align:middle;">Download the free trial for a
                taste of what our powerful 
                software can do!<br><a href="google.com"><button style="padding:0.5em 0.5em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;margin-left:75px;margin-top:10px;">DOWNLOAD</button></a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#trial').hide();
  $('#trial').delay(500).show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
  $("#trial").hover(function(){
    $("#trial").css("transition","all .5s ease-in-out");
    },function(){
    $("#trial").css("transition","all .5s ease-in-out");
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#trial{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(300px);
    -ms-transform:translateX(300px);
    -moz-transform:translateX(300px);
    background: darkred;
    padding-left:30px;
    font-size:80%;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}

#trial:hover{
    -ms-transform:translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform:translateX(0px);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0px);
    -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400 ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: anything;  
}

#trial button{
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Although jsfiddle is helpful, You should add your code in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use jQuery, you can do this in CSS3 only:

```
#trial{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(300px);
    -ms-transform:translateX(300px);
    -moz-transform:translateX(300px);
    background: darkred;
    padding-left:30px;
    font-size:80%;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;

    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400 ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}


#trial:hover {
    -ms-transform:translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform:translateX(0px);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0px);
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q75x97zj/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using negative margin values instead of translatex to hide part of your div. Then use css3 transition on margin with ease-in-out etc.

Answer (score 0):

well you seem to do the work with css3 and jquery all together. You can do this with only using css or only usig jquery.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#trial').hide().delay(500).show('slide', {
           direction: 'right'
       }, 500)
           .mouseenter(function () {
           $(this).animate({
               right: "+=300"
           }, 400);
       }).mouseleave(function () {
           $(this).animate({
               right: "-=300"
           }, 400);
       });
   });
```

[here i fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q75x97zj/6/). and try to avoid inline styling give some class names to your elements you'll be happier when you need to change something.

Answer (score 0):

Remove style from #trial div and use this css.
Remove all javascript code...not used in this case  :)

Change your CSS with:

```
#trial {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    top:80px;
    right:-320px;
    background: darkred;
    padding-left:30px;
    font-size:80%;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    #trial:hover{
     right: 0;  
    }
```

In general, you should move the style rules used within your HTML in the style sheet. This will allow you to better maintain your code.
I hope it's useful.