# Chrome Getting more margin than Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, margin

[this is my website](http://iqc.ddns.net/)

in the second page ( the founders boxes )

```
<div class="socials1"> ...</div>
```

in **firefox** the margin  are just fine with

`.socials1 { margin-top:55px;}`

while **in chrome** i got to make it : 
`.socials1 { margin-top:25px;}`

could any one tell me if there is  a way to fix this or i got to use user-agent detection and load different css's ?

Comment: what ? :D what do you mean up more

Comment: you can see it in the website i have written the link in the first line .

Comment: the css is so complicated so its kinda impossible to write

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. While Chrome is quite inconsistent with CSS and is getting worse every time, in your case I see it looks the same both in FF and Chrome exception made that in FF you don't have any social link displaying (point for Chrome). I can see you have margin-top:55px, works the same in both browsers, really not getting your question at all

Comment: CSS is never complicated...
If you want the problem fixed, it is a good way to isolate the problem in a small fiddle. You can't expect others to do that for you...

Comment: in Chrome [link](http://i.imgur.com/02p64fo.png) you can see the social icons are clipped because the margin-top is 55px , if i set it to 25px it would be perfect . but in the same time when the margin is 55px it is perfectly shown in firefox [link](http://puu.sh/bzTmu/cbb12891f2.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements