# Bootstrap navbar appears differently in Firefox and Chrome due to browser rendering inconsistencies

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

The screenshot below is my bootstrap navbar which works nicely (pills disappear one by one as per spec). However when scaled down to various screen sizes, the navbar is no longer in-line and becomes staggered.

The issue is worse in Chrome than in Firefox because the left hand section of the navbar does not sit at the top of the screen.

If I can get Chrome to look like the Firefox screenshot, this will help me fix the remaining issues.

Can anyone suggest which browser rendering inconsistency would explain why on the Chrome version, the left hand portion of the navbar does not sit flush with the top of the screen?

Top is Chrome, bottom is FireFox.

[image: Screenshot showing Chrome and Firefox differences]

```
   <header>
        <div class="vr-nav-container" data-ng-controller="navBarController">
            <div>
                <div class="col vr-nav-col1">
                    <div class="nowrap">
                        <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top no-padding"  role="navigation"'>
                            <a class='navbar-brand' href='/Default'>
                                <img height="30" class="logo" alt="Flatty" src="/Assets/images/logo-small-rocket-lg.png" />
                                <img height="30" id="xs-toggler" class="logo-xs" alt="Flatty" src="/Assets/images/logo_xs.png" />
                            </a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col vr-nav-col2 fill center">
                    <div class="nowrap">
                        <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top " role="navigation"'>
                            <div class="tabbable ">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills contrast-background">
                                    <li data-ng-repeat="item in NavBarViewModel">
                                        <a href="{{item.Path}}"><i class="{{item.Icon}}"></i>

                                            {{item.Title}}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col vr-nav-col3">
                    <div class="nowrap">
                        <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"  role="navigation"'>
                            <ul class='nav'>
                                <li ng-controller="awardBoxController" class='dropdown medium only-icon widget'>
                                    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
                                        <i class='icon-trophy'></i>
                                        <div class='label'>{{AwardSummary.TotalPoints}}</div>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="box-content box-statistic">
                                                <h3 class="title text-error">{{AwardSummary.Level}}</h3>
                                                <small>{{AwardSummary.TotalPoints}} points</small>
                                                <div class="text-banana icon-trophy align-right"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="/#/Awards/My-Points/">
                                            <div class='points-history box-content  widget-body'>
                                                <div class='pull-left icon'>
                                                    <i class='icon- text-banana'></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class='pull-left text'>
                                                    <span><strong>Point History</strong> <span class="see-all">- see all</span></span>
                                                    <small class='text-muted'>{{award.AcheivedDate}}</small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a></li>
                                        <li ng-repeat="award in AwardSummary.Awards">
                                            <a href='#'>
                                                <div class=' box-content  widget-body'>
                                                    <div class='pull-left icon'>
                                                        <i class='icon-{{award.Icon}} text-success'></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class='pull-left text'>
                                                        {{award.Name}}
                     <span class="text-muted">+{{award.Points}}</span>
                                                        <small class='text-muted'>{{award.AcheviedDate| fromNow}}</small>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class='divider'></li>
                                        <li class='widget-footer'>
                                            <a href='/#/Awards/High-Scores/'>High Scores</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class='dropdown medium user-menu'>
                                    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
                                        <img width="23" height="23" src="/Assets/images/avatar.jpg" />
                                        <span class='user-name'>
                                            <asp:Literal ID="UserFirstNameLiteral" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="UserFirstNameLiteral">FirstName LastName</asp:Literal></span>
                                        <b class='caret'></b>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href='/UserAccount/UserProfile'>
                                                <i class='icon-user'></i>
                                                <%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("MasterPage","Profile") %>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a ng-if="ShowSettings" href='/Settings/Dashboard'>
                                                <i class='icon-cog'></i>
                                                <%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","Settings") %>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a ng-if="ShowSettings" href='http://todo.help.vr.zendeskurl.com'>
                                                <i class='icon-bullhorn'></i>
                                                <%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("MasterPage","GetHelp") %>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class='divider'></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <form runat="server">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="SignOutLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="SignOutLinkButton_Click" meta:resourcekey="SignOutLinkButton">
                                <i class='icon-signout'></i>       <%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","SignOut") %>
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </form>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class='navbar-form navbar-right hidden-xs'>
                                <button class='btn btn-link dropdown-toggle' style="top: 4px;" name='button' data-toggle="dropdown" type='submit'><i class="icon-search"></i><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a category="" class="searchoption" href="#"><%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("MasterPage","Everything") %></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a category="Deals" class="searchoption" href="#"><%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","Deals") %></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a category="Contacts" class="searchoption" href="#"><%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","Contacts") %></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a category="Accounts" class="searchoption" href="#"><%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","Accounts") %></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a category="Tasks" class="searchoption" href="#"><%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","Tasks") %></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class='form-group'>
                                    <input value="" id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder='<%= this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources","Search") %>...' autocomplete="off" id="q_header" name="q" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

I am using the default bootstrap 3.0 CSS and have a seperate CSS file overriding some default CSS and adding my own

I had to do this because the pills section has to be in its own div in the centre column in order to work (disappear one by one and 'stack' as width decreases) and fill all the width between the left and right cols in the navbar.

```
.navbar-collapse:after {
    clear: none;
}

.sorting, .sorting_asc, .sorting_desc {
    background : none;
}

.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}

.removeclass{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.removeclass:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
}


.vr-navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.rightnav {
     float: right;
  width: 285px; 
  margin-left: -160px; 

}

.leftnav {
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding:0 10px;
    width:auto;

    height: 40px;
}

.nav-pills {
    height: 40px;
}


.hidden-xs {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.hidden-xs {
  display: none!important;
 }
}

.current {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-pills li a {
    color: white;
}

        .vr-nav-container
        {
            display: table;
        }

            .vr-nav-container > div
            {
                display: table-row;
            }

                .vr-nav-container > div > div
                {
                    display: table-cell;
                }

                .vr-nav-container > div > div
                {
                    padding: 0em;
                }

            .vr-nav-container .nowrap
            {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            .vr-nav-container .fill
            {
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .vr-nav-container .center
            {
                text-align: center;
            }

        .vr-nav-col1
        {
            /*background: red;*/
            width: 5%;
            min-width: 50px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .vr-nav-col2
        {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /*background: yellow;*/
        }

        .vr-nav-col3
        {
            /*background: green;*/
            width: 40%;
            /*min-width: 260px;*/
        }

        .no-padding
        {
            padding-left: 0px !important;
            padding-right: 0px !important;
        }

  .main-nav-closed #main-nav .navigation > .nav > li:hover > a.toggler-flyout > span
{
    display: none;
}
    /*.main-nav-closed #main-nav .navigation > .nav > li:hover > a.toggler-flyout > i
{
         content: "\f061"; 
}*/
```

Comment: Would love to see some code

Comment: we all help Tyrion, come on! :D But really, please post your CSS, you're not using the default Bootstrap so without seeing your CSS code it's impossible to tell (and yes, chances are the issue is in that CSS code you're not posting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements